# Why is my update data running on install?

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions, ee-1.13.0.2

I tested a fresh install of my extension, but the data-upgrade script is running. It should only run on upgrade, correct?

Update data path: `magento/app/code/community/Example/Ex/data/ex_setup/data-upgrade-2.2.3-2.3.0.php`

Install script path: `magento/app/code/community/Example/Ex/sql/ex_setup/mysql4-install-2.0.0.php`

config.xml: `<version>2.3.0</version>`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

renamed `mysql4-install-2.0.0.php` to `mysql4-install-2.3.0.php`

Comment: I suggest looking for some resources on Magento install and data scripts. They are quite interesting.